# Please open the comment help "Learn more..." link in a new window

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

Right now clicking it opens in the parent and the draft of the comment you are typing is lost when clicking the back button, at least in firefox 5.

This situation is brought on particularly since the "help" link can't be clicked with the mouse wheel to open in a new tab, so it is counter intuitive to try that then with the "learn more..." link.

Comment: +1 for the 2nd paragraph

Comment: @ChrisF - still it violates the "Don't make me think" principle.  Help links shouldn't be destructive when clicked and you shouldn't have to know that you have to do something other than a "normal" mouse click to make it work correctly.  The extended q/a editor help does work like suggested and should be the model used in all similar situtations.  Relying on the behavior of the back button in a browser to preserve what you've typed isn't a reasonable alternative, either. While I'd normally prefer a dialog there's probably too much content for that.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I misread the question so my comment is wrong. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good point. I'm generally very careful with using `target="_blank"`, but in this case, I agree with you. After the next build, that link goes to a new tab.

Comment: fair enough, thats quick. Actually, it is probably the quickest resolution of all the bugs I ever filed in my life. Maybe I shall have to file some more here... Thanks